# ip tunnel from subnet to local host

Tags: tunneling

I'm very new to Linux networking.

I need to set up an IP tunnel so that all udp traffic coming to the 12.x.x.x subnet gets tunneled to a specific ip and port on the same box so that my application can receive it.

I'm trying this:
ip tunnel add mytunnel mode ipip remote 127.0.0.1 ttl inherit
ip route add 12.0.0.0/8 dev mytunnel metric 1

But when I create a UDP client and server application which sends packets to 12.1.1.1:45000 and a server that listens on 127.0.0.1:45000 the server never receives the packets.

Thanks

Comment: If you need to redirect traffic, what you're looking for is not a IP-in-IP tunnel but more probably a firewall redirection.
And by the way, domain 12.0.0.0/8 is not a private range of IPs. Are you using it for your subnet?

Comment: I'm not looking to simply redirect traffic but to intercept it so that I can translate it to a different protocol on a totally different bus.

Comment: Also I realize that the 12 network is not private. It doesn't need to be for my purpose.

Comment: You should put this information in your question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: You are aware that a tunnel needs two endpoints, and you can't just "intercept" the tunnelled packets? If you need to run some program ("server") that converts packets send to some interface, use a `tun` interface. That's for example how VPN servers work. See e.g. `Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt` in the kernel source.

Comment: Thank you, Igeorget.  I was under the impression that "ip tunnel" was the new way to do tun.  Is that the case?  As I said I'm very new new Linux networking.